# computing (a^b)%m in java

Tags: java, math, long-integer

While trying to implement the [Miller-Rabin primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) I came across a strange behaviour of java. Regard the following code:
`long x = (long) (Math.pow(a, b));`
For a and b large enough (doesn't need that much) you will always get x = 9223372036854775807 = `Long.MAX_VALUE` instead of an overflow value.
This result is completely useless and won't help calculating (a^b)%m, which is what we need.
Now since (a^b)%m would easily fit into 64 bits when (a^b) doesn't, I wonder if there is a way to calculate this number without using `BigInteger`?

Comment: I think you already know the answer: `Now since (a^b)%m would easily fit into 64 bits when (a^b) doesn't`. By the way, what's wrong with `BigInteger`?

Comment: You could work with double, that is after all what pow returns. However, to really use big integers you would need... BigInteger!

Comment: You can read about the properties of modular arithmetic on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Properties)

Comment: I don't use double because double is inprecise. Why should i already know the answer @x80486? i don't get your point.

Comment: ...you already know that `a^b` won't always fit for `long` types, hence you need to use a `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always implement the pow(...) yourself and mod as often as possible. Generally speaking (in pseudo-code):

```
powMod(a, b, m) {
    result = 1
    for (i = 0; i < b; i++) {
        result = (result * a) % m
    }
    return result
}
```

If `result * a` may be too large then you may want to implement `*` by repeated addition and modding after each `+`. Furthermore you can (and should) always use `a' = a % m` and `b' = b % m` if you don't do that already.

Comment: As an addendum to this: `c mod m = (a ⋅ b) mod m = [(a mod m) ⋅ (b mod m)] mod m`, due to distribution. This naturally extends to exponentiation. Just to qualify your suggestion to "mod as often as possible".

Comment: This works, but is computationally expensive. Search for "efficient exponentiation" for an explanation as to why this approach is slow and how to improve it

Answer (score 1):

Use `BigInteger`, in particular the method `modPow()`. From the javadocs:

> `public BigInteger modPow(BigInteger exponent, BigInteger m)` - Returns a `BigInteger` whose value is (`this`^`exponent` mod `m`). (Unlike `pow`, this method permits negative exponents.)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow(java.math.BigInteger,%20java.math.BigInteger)

For Example:

```
BigInteger a = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
BigInteger b = BigInteger.valueOf(3);
BigInteger m = BigInteger.valueOf(7);

BigInteger result = a.modPow(b, m);  // i.e. 2 ^ 3 mod 7 -> 8 mod 7 -> 1
System.out.println(result);  // prints 1
```